# How to exclude a specific dependency in package json by gitignore

Tags: node-modules, gitignore

I am got a problem with `node-sass` module when I am building the project using ReactJs. It could not build successfully in distinguished devices (such as window and mac M1). I can fixed the trouble on each device by upgrading or downgrading the version of `node-sass` to compatible with `node` versions.
I've just only think the way to solve it by excluding the modules when I push code to git on each device and by the way the project will be still updated with the remained modules in `package.json`.

I just want to ask how can I exclude just only one node-sass to the pushing and still keep the another packages? Please give me a reason if not. I just want to discuss about this problem. Otherwise, I will find the way to remove it from my project, later.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to develop in a container environment. You can check [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).